# SoapClient fails to connect

Tags: php, soap

I am trying to make a Soap connection to SugarCRM.  My URL links to a WSDL file, bu the following code:

```
<?php

$soapClient = new SoapClient("http://mysite.sugarondemand.com/soap.php?wsdl"); 
var_dump($soapClient);

?>
```

produces the following result: object(SoapClient)#1 (2) { ["_soap_version"]=>  int(1) ["sdl"]=>  resource(1) of type (Unknown) }

Does anyone know what could be going on?

Answer (score 23):

Everything is fine here. This is how soapClient object looks after connection. If you want for example see functions list, use:

```
$functions = $soapClient->__getFunctions ();
var_dump ($functions);
```

Comment: +1 for the correct answer but not accepted by the author. Hmm.